# Git add-publish existing project using VS 2015 gui

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

VS 2015 invited me to GIT 'publish' an existing web site I'm working on to visualStudio.com.  I clicked 'get started' and the publish screen, correctly, requests three 'levels' for publishing (below).

Level 1: Account URL
Level 2: Team Project
Levle 3: Repo Name

However, it is not allowing me to change level 2: 'Team Project'.  I can change 1 and 3, but 2 is locked into an unrelated project I created a while ago. I can't edit it.  There is a DDL, but the selections are also non-related projects.

There's nothing fancy about the web site.  Its a regular site, containing all the files required beneath a single folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the VS GUI to do this, but the steps below did accomplish the goal...

1. create a new 'team project' at visualstudio.com
2. connect to that team project in VS 2015
3. After connecting you should be given the option to toggle on the new project, do that.
4. In 'team explorer' window double click the new project
5. You'll be given the option to 'clone this repository'
6. Clone it to a new directory (it won't let you clone to an existing directory)
7. Copy all your files into the directory you just created
8. Open the team explorer - changes window
9. Sync

Comment: the method above works but it won't keep your change history.  You'll need Chocolatey for that:  http://chriskirby.net/blog/migrate-an-existing-project-from-tfs-to-github-with-changeset-history-intact